# How to display elements ID using prev and next (and the next's next) in Jquery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-selectors, javascript

I have several li floating left, I know that I can identify the ID of the "next" li by using:

```
$("li").live("click",function(e) {
    alert($(this).next("li").attr('id'))
});
```

When you click an li it will display the ID of the next li.

But how do you display the ID of the next li's, next li?

```
For example,

If I have:

1 2 3 4 5 6

And I move the number 2 to make:

1 3 4 5 2 6
```

How do I return that the "next" value to 1 has changed to 3, the "next" value to 2 has changed to 6 and the "next" value to 5 has change to 2?

**In other words, how will I know what numbers "next" value has changed?**

I am asking because I need to be able to identify these values and store them in a database so that I can load the page and echo the li's in the correct floated order using PHP if they are rearranged. I will be using ajax of course to send these values to a PHP page.

Here is the document:

http://jsfiddle.net/TSM_mac/uuHsg/2/

Also, I am using alert(something...) to display the results.

Is there any type of "onrelease" or similar command that will only display the values after the objects are rearranged?

Thanks tons,

taylor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely clear on what you're trying to accomplish, but the `sortable` widget does have a [`change`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-change) event handler that you can tap into to determine when a sortable element's position in the DOM has changed:

```
$("#sortable").sortable({
    change: function() { ... }
});
```

I've worked on a few projects where we have to allow the user to sort items, saving that sort to the database. I would let your server-side code handle that logic and pass up the new order (either by listening to the `change` event or the [`stop`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#event-stop) event).

Answer (score 0):

The next "li"'s next "li" is :

```
$("li").live("click",function(e) {
    alert($(this).next("li").next("li").attr('id'))
});
```

Comment: Yes ok that is good. But I just realized a problem...

If I have:

1 2 3 4 5 6

And I move 2 to :

1 3 4 5 2 6

How will I know what Li's I need to find the "Next" Li.. How will I know what next's have changed?

Comment: i would maintain a javascript array and move the position in the array when moving the li and that way you can always refer to the array via javascript to know the positions

Comment: Ok. It thought of that, but the problem is that the li's are created dynamically, and I want them to be able to be moved from parent div to parent div (the parent divs are created dynamically as well). The "next" value of the Li's will change depending on which parent div they are in, so storing it in an array I do not think will work.